# Calculated field in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have tried to create a calculated field that will show the number of customer transactions processed within 15 minutes.

I have added the expression:

```
=count(fields!wait.Value<15)
```

However, when I run the query I'm getting the error message : `'expression used for the calculated field includes an aggregate RowNumber...'`

Can you advise please on how to create a calculated field so I can capture the value I want?

I have tried `= SUM(IIF(Fields!wait.Value < 15 , 1, 0))` to no avail.

With many thanks.

Comment: The error message sounds like it relates to something else in your report. Does your report run successfully when you remove this expression?

Comment: Is there any other calculated field ? Because your second expression should have worked.

Comment: Thanks both for your replies. The report runs fine when the expression is removed; there is no other calculated field. However I am continuing investiagtions and hopefully will sort it out.

Answer (score 1):

Calculated fields added to datasets can't have aggregate functions. The calculated field is essentially adding an extra *column* to your dataset. It sounds like you may want a variable? Used elsewhere in the report, your second expression would work, or the similar

```
=Count(IIf(Fields!wait.Value<15, 1, Nothing))
```

would work too.